# Why is returning only one object in for in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm making an app in react and I don't know why when I'm using for-in loop that returns only the first object, not all of them. My expected output is like in `arr.map()` but unfortunately I'm not able to that using objects instead of arrays.

```js
places: {
  place_1: {
    title: 'Place 1',
  },
  place_2: {
    title: 'Place 2',
  },
  place_3: {
    title: 'Place 3',
  },
}


const App = () => {

 const handleMenu = () => {
    for (const key in places) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(places, key)) {
        return (
          <h1>
            title={places[key].title}
          </h1>
        );
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {handleMenu()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: because return exits.....

Comment: so how to avoid it to return all of the things?

Comment: Why the `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(places, key)` instead of `places.hasOwnProperty(key)`?

Comment: You need to *gather* "all of the things", and then `return` *that*.

Comment: Convert your object into something you can loop over Object.keys() Object.values() Object.entries()

Comment: `Object.values(places).map(place => .........)`